# Neo4j: delete self relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In Cypher (Neo4j), I am able to delete relationship using id. But When I try to delete self relationship, query is running for long time and relationship is not deleted.

I have tried following many ways:

1. `start r=rel(5828) delete r;`
2. `MATCH (p:Person{fid:'60'})-[r:IS_RELATED_TO]->(p:Person{fid:'60'})` delete r
3. `match (a:Person)-[rel:IS_RELATED_TO]->(b:Person) where a.fid="60" and ID(rel)=5828 delete rel`

But not able to delete from any above way.

Screenshot to delete self relationship using id:

[image]

Comment: What version of Neo4j are you using?

Comment: I tried here with `create (node:Node {name : "Bruno"}), (node)-[:rel]->(node)` then `match (a:Node {name:"Bruno"})-[r:rel]->(b:Node {name:"Bruno"})
delete r` and the relationships was deleted. Using Neo4j 3.3.1 here.

Comment: Thanks @Bruno Peres. You done it by changing a to b. Thats working fine.

Comment: But i would like to know why it cannot be deleted using ID (start r=rel(5828) delete r;) ?

Comment: AzarEJ - Well, I don't know exactly, but note that `START` clause is [deprecated](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/start/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the relationship you want to delete does not actually have the native ID `5828`. And it also looks like `Person` node with that relationship does not actually have the `fid` value "60".

If you just want to delete *all* self-relationships involving `Person` labels and `IS_RELATED_TO` types, this should work (assuming that `Person` nodes have unique `fid` values):

```
MATCH (a:Person)-[rel:IS_RELATED_TO]->(a) 
DELETE rel;
```

Comment: Thanks @cybersam. Thats working fine. 
But i would like to know why it cannot be deleted using ID (start r=rel(5828) delete r;) ?

Comment: You *can* delete a relationship using its native ID, but you have to use the right ID. Something like this would tell you the right native ID(s): `MATCH (a:Person)-[rel:IS_RELATED_TO]->(a) RETURN ID(rel);` Using an actual native ID, your 1st query should have worked.